# Doxygen fails to notice duplicates due to namespace

Tags: doxygen

When I run Doxygen against some 3rd-party libraries I'd like documented, it fails to identify some entries as duplicates.  It looks as if some code uses the namespace, and some code (already in that namespace?) is leaving out the namespace which results in Doxygen getting confused.

For example, when I look at the class index page or the class member page, the pages it generates might include all of these as if they were 4 different calls:

- `foo::bar( aaa::bbb )`
- `foo::bar( bbb )`
- `bar( aaa::bbb )`
- `bar( bbb )`

In reality, these are all exactly the same methods and the parameters passed in are also exactly the same.  Not only does this cause some confusion, but it takes hours longer than necessary to generate documents since there are so many duplicates.

I'm hoping there is a setting I've somehow missed in the Doxygen config file which I can tweak either to help Doxygen ignore duplicates or to better identify these duplicates?

I'm using Doxygen v1.8.1.2 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: If doxygen knows that foo and aaa are namespaces (i.e. they are part of the input parsed by doxygen) then it would be able to figure out that all are indeed the same function.

Comment: Thanks, @Doxygen. Anything specific you can think of we can do to prevent duplicates like this: https://bug696925.bugzilla-attachments.gnome.org/attachment.cgi?id=240187

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer (yet) but I created a bug against Doxygen in March 2013:  https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=696925