# Doxygen does not handle using namespace directive

Tags: c++, doxygen

I have the following source files:

`headers/header.h`:

```
namespace internal {
    class C {};
}
```

`sources/a.h`:

```
#include <header.h>

namespace global {
    void f(internal::C c); 
}
```

`sources/a.cpp`:

```
#include "a.h"

namespace global {
    using internal::C;
    void f(C c) {}
}
```

I want to generate Doxygen documentation on `sources` directory, while `headers` is a standalone headers directory. So I put `headers/` in `INCLUDE_PATH` in Doxygen config and run Doxygen from `sources` directory.

What I want to see in namespace `global` is one function `f(internal::C)`. What I get is two functions, `f(C)` and `f(internal::C)`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15398591/) question refers to the similar issue but

1. that bug seems to be fixed already and
2. namespace internal should be recognized by Doxygen parser as long as I provide a path to it in `INCLUDE_PATH`.

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've seen it mentioned that Doxygen is not a compiler front end, it is a lexer. As such, it does not have access to the full structure of your code.

Comment: @KhouriGiordano Sure it does not. Though if I put this header.h file into the project directory (and generate doxygen docs for it too) these two functions are correctly recognized as one. So technically there is a possibility to recognize using's. The problem occurs only with headers from INCLUDE_PATH.